# How to make more than one game object appear with the same code?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm newbie trying to build a game. I have an ant when you click on it it disappears and appears again somewhere else.

I want to make more than one ant appear at the same time and they get destroyed when you click on them. Also I want all of them move randomly from the top of the screen to the bottom of the screen. How to do so?

```
var ant : GameObject;
var scoreText : GameObject;
var livesText : GameObject;
var walkingSpeed : double;
var livesNumber : int;
var scoreNumber : int;

function Start () {
    ant = GameObject.Find("Ant");
    scoreText = GameObject.Find("Score");
    livesText = GameObject.Find("Lives");

    //Initialize the values of walking speed
    walkingSpeed = 0.0;
    livesNumber = 3;
    scoreNumber = 0;

    //Initialize the GUI components
    livesText.GetComponent(UI.Text).text = "Lives Remaining: " + livesNumber;
    scoreText.GetComponent(UI.Text).text = "Score: " + scoreNumber;

    //Place the ant in a random position on start of the game
    ant.transform.position.x = generateX();
    ant.transform.position.y = generateY();
}

function Update () {    

    if(ant.transform.position.y < -4.35 && livesNumber > 0){    

        livesNumber -= 1;
        livesText.GetComponent(UI.Text).text = "Lives Remaining: " + livesNumber;
        generateCoordinates();

    }else if(ant.transform.position.y < -4.35 && livesNumber == 0){
        Destroy(GameObject.Find("Ant"));
        gameOver();

    }else{

        ant.transform.position.y -= walkingSpeed;
    }
}

function gameOver(){    
    Application.LoadLevel("GameOver");
}


//Generates random x
function generateX(){
    var x = Random.Range(-2.54,2.54);
    return x;
}

//Generates random y
function generateY(){
    var y = Random.Range(-4.0,3.8);
    return y;
}

//Move the "Ant" to the new coordiantess
function generateCoordinates(){
    //You clicked it!
    scoreNumber += 1;

    //Update the score display
    scoreText.GetComponent(UI.Text).text = "Score: " + scoreNumber;
    ant.transform.position.x = generateX();
    ant.transform.position.y = generateY();
}

//If tapped or clicked
function OnMouseDown(){
    //Place the ant at another point
    generateCoordinates();

    //Increase the walking speed by 0.01
    walkingSpeed += 0.01;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, UnityScript is now deprecated for a while, so I think a good practice should be to update your Unity version and code in C# as now it's the main language used.

Try to avoid `Game.Find()` which is not a good way to reference GameObject. Instead you could create a prefab of your 'ant' and instantiate it as many time you want in random positions like that :

```
public GameObject antPrefab;

void GenerateAnt()
{
  //create a new position from random X and Y
  Vector2 position = new Vector2(generateX(), generateY());

  //Instantiate a new ant gameobject from the prefab and set position and rotation
  GameObject newAnt = Instantiate(antPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity)
}
```

Now if you have multiple ants, you need to loop for each ant to update the position of each ant.

Don't forget to link your prefab in your public field in the editor ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is made around having only one specific ant. You need to make the code agnostic to specific ants.

But before going into specifics;

- Please consider moving to C#, it'll make your life a lot easier.
- I will assume this is 2D. If 3d, simply change the Vector2s to Vector3 and remove 2d from trigger method.
- I'll write the example code in C#

So basically, what you have today is:

- Spawn an ant.
- If user clicks the ant, move it to start.
- If ant goes too far, you lose a life & remove it.

What you want it

- Spawn any number of ants in random position.
- If user clicks an ant, remove it(?).
- If ant reaches goal, you lose a life & remove it.

So let's address every single one of these steps, and how I'd implement them:

### Spawn any number of ants, in random position

#### Spawning requires 2 things:

1. A prefab
2. Usage of `Instantiate()`

If you don't know how to create a prefab, or what it is, I suggest googling around until you understand. In short, it's an instance of a GameObject saved to disk. [You do this by simply dragging a GameObject to a folder in the inspector's project view.](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/CreatingPrefabs.html)

```
public GameObject antPrefab;
```

```
GameObject SpawnAnt(Vector2 position) {
    return Instantiate<GameObject>(antPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

#### Random position

How I like doing spawn positions is by declaring a spawn area GameObject, which you can move around in the editor, and specifying the size as a serialized field:

```
[Range(1f, 10f)] // Gives you a slider to drag between 1 and 10 for this variable
public float spawnAreaRadius;

public Transform spawnArea;
```

```
void Vector2 GetRandomSpawnPosition() {
    var spawnAreaCenter = spawnArea.position;
    var spawnRandomX = Random.Range(-spawnAreaRadius, spawnAreaRadius);
    var spawnRandomY = Random.Range(-spawnAreaRadius, spawnAreaRadius);
    return new Vector2(spawnRandomX, spawnRandomY);
}
```

And regarding spawning multiple, you'd probably want to put up some event/timer to spawn and increase the ants to make it progressively harder:

Call this when you want to spawn a certain amount of ants in a random pattern around your spawn position:

```
void SpawnAnts(int num) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
         var pos = GetRandomSpawnPosition();
         SpawnAnt(pos);
    }

}
```

#### Ant movement & lifecycle

Instead of looping over all ants and moving them with an overhead controller, which may be the optimal solution, for the sake of simplicity I'd add a script to the antPrefab that contains the ants:

(This component requires a rigidbody & collider)

```
void Update() {
    // Move ant towards goal
}

void OnMouseDown() {
    Destroy();
}
```

This will also give you a chance to easily give different ants different speeds, etc. Make each ant's AI a bit unique with far less effort than if they were grouped together.

#### Colliding with goal

Define an area which is the ant's goal by placing a Trigger Collider in your world. Add your existing script to it and add a method for detecting collisions:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) {
     if (col.tag == "ant") {
           lives--;
           Destroy(col.gameObject);    
     }

}
```

### Summary

Some of these things you already solved in your way (such as generateX()), I wanted to give you some insight in how I'd personally tackle your code. You should evaluate which parts you'd want to use.

---

Disclaimer: This achieves your requirements, but leaves you with some other limitations, such as adding points when clicking an ant requires you to, probably, call some singleton point manager from the ant, rather than just detecting it in the same controller, which also would handle points.